# What is the status of SUSY GUTs in 2018?

Tags: experimental-physics, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification, proton-decay

Grand unification theories (GUTs) generically predict proton decay, and many of them have been under pressure for decades as experiments have failed to see it. I don't think there have been recent experiments along these lines, and proton decay rates do vary between GUTs, so I expect the situation here hasn't changed much recently and isn't too interesting.

However, supersymmetric GUTs are motivated by improved gauge coupling unification, which only works if the superpartners are sufficiently light. [Back in 2011](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/are-non-supersymmetric-guts-ruled-out-due-to-lack-of-precise-gauge-coupling-unif), somebody asked whether the LHC had ruined this, but it was certainly too early to say. Now in 2018 much more data has been released. What is the status of SUSY GUTs today?